# why installing a new application in linux is so complex..?

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

Why installing or uninstalling a new application in linux is so complex? why there is no installer like windows installer which would help users without prior knowledge about linux command line (like me) to install new programs..?

Comment: apt-get update && apt-get install foo or on a rpm system yum install foo. Not really all that hard. See also - see also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Comment: which application are you having trouble with? and don't worry, it gets easier.

Comment: A better question would be "why is installing (and upgrading) things on windows (and mac) so cumbersome, so manual, so inconsistent across applications, and in general a PITA?"..... But since macs are also now using (essentially) a package manager (the app store), I'm sure windows will soon follow. Then linux (et al.) will be more intuitive for new users.

Comment: Have you used Ubuntu Software Center? It is by far, much superior than Windows or Mac "installation systems". It is a front-end for "apt-get / dpkg", which is stable, very well documented, standardized, supports upgrades or downgrades... Also, you can download, for example, `google-chrome-stable.deb` and double click on it, to install it, easier, than running random *.exe files on Windows.

Comment: I've already said I'm new to ubuntu. That may be the reason I felt it so hard to install or change any program. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: "*apt-get update && apt-get install foo or on a rpm system yum install foo. Not really all that hard.*" -- It's hard enough for a non-tech-savvy user especially if they never used a similar operating system before. They tend to be scared of the keyboard, so an installer where you can click `next` using your mouse is more comfortable. The software center does help with this to a point. Unfortunately, if they stick with ubuntu long enough they'll end up bumping into an application that is not there.

Comment: @Daniel- I think you are confusing new with complex. If a user is not willing to give a new OS time to learn new things they will become frustrated and fail. Newer versions of Windows, 8 in particular, are not very easy or intuitive either. For example, I found it difficult to print from MS word because they have changed the menues from the way it was when I used Windows 95. You need to be more open minded when you stat a new OS and read the documentation.

Comment: I feel as if this is an opinionated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to using package managers [either terminal or GUI], then it is fairly easy.

If you are referring to compiling software from source, then that is a bit more complex but you will find it easier.

You will find both easier as time goes on.

Comment: Hopefully this particular new user isn't starting with Arch linux....

Comment: @michael_n pacman isn't that hard.

Answer (score 6):

If you aren't used to something it doesn't mean it is more complex.

In fact installing under Ubuntu is easier!

By default package management is held by **Ubuntu Software Center** where you install an application with **one click** on **Install** button instead of ***Next - Next - Install - OK*** in Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Linux makes it a lot easier to install software. The problem is that most people are so hung up (used to) the Microsoft way that they find hard to install it on Linux.

Most Linux distros give you a repository of applications that you can install at the tip of you fingers. You can use command line commands to download and install from repos, the software center (gui interface for repos), distro specific packages (like deb or rpm) that can be installed via command line or by double clicking on them, source packages that can be compiled and installed, other user's repos (like ppa for Ubuntu), and more.

Again, it's not that is hard to install, is just that most people are not familiar with it.

Keep at it and ask the right questions. You only have to gain from it.