# one click software installation

Tags: package-management

friends,

i am very new to ubuntu,and is been using this incredible thing from past few days,
it's a really very new experience for me,i would like to know about one click install methods as like in windows we found .exe softwares every where, is there any method?
and please do suggest me some awesome websites for repository's.
Thanks

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/585628/why-installing-a-new-application-in-linux-is-so-complex/585656#585656  and here: http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/installingsoftware

Answer (score 0):

Installer files in Ubuntu are .deb, they work like .exe, click them to install alternatively use the software center, thousand of apps all one click install.

You can install gdebi

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

And open .debs with this to replicate the Windows installers but it is not required as they just open in software center.

For repos ubuntu-universe is the main one and is pre-installed, most apps are published here and show in software center.

Get a bit of practice before worrying about other repo's, as they usually only contain one or two programs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely certain if you mean one step installation of Ubuntu or one step installation of software.  The software center contains the fastest, most convenient software installer I've ever seen.  Windows users become instantly envious when they see it.